# Getting 'permission denied for table foo' error even though permissions have been granted

Tags: postgresql, database-permissions

I have logged into my database as the database owner (a superuser as well) and have created a `role_write` role with nologin and noinherit flags.

I've revoked the default create permissions from the public schema with:

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
```

And revoked public access to the database with:

```
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE mydb FROM PUBLIC;
```

I have granted roles on each table I want the role to be able to have read/write access. Using the `user` table for this example, I have added:

```
grant insert, select, update, delete on users to role_write;
```

Then I've also given the user proper permissions for the tables, schema, sequences and database connection and altered the default privileges with:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE my to role_write;
grant usage on schema public to role_write;
grant select, insert, update, delete on all tables in schema public to role_write;
grant usage, select on all sequences in schema public to role_write;
alter default privileges in schema public
   grant select, insert, update, delete on tables to role_write;
alter default privileges in schema public
   grant usage, select on sequences to role_write;
```

I have also created a new user (with noinherit flag) and have added the role_write role to this user with:

```
grant role_write to newuser;
```

Then I signed in as that user as ran:

```
set role role_write;
```

Then just to be safe, I restarted postgres.

Yet even after all that, when I try to connect to the database through sequelize/apollo server as newuser and run a query, I get the error:

```
permission denied for table users
```

I have no idea what I've done wrong. If I check the privileges of the user table it shows that role_write is correctly setup.

Any help?

**EDIT:** So I've realized that I need to run `set role role_write` on every session, not just once. If I connect to the database and run a query straight away then I get the error, however if I first set the role then it allows me.

### So my question now is...

How do I get sequelize/apollo to add `set role role_write;` for each new connection to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*DEAR PEOPLE FROM THE FUTURE: Here's what we've figured out so far ...*

As explained in my edit, the issue is that I created the newuser with the `noinherit` flag. This causes an issue when using sequelize/apollo as the only way to get the read/write permissions from the role_write role is by first running `set role role_write;`.

Maybe someone will answer with a solution that lets you send `set role role_write;` with each sequelize/apollo request to the server, but for now I solved the issue by simply running `alter role newuser with inherit;`. Now I don't get the error message anymore.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is

```
ALTER ROLE newuser INHERIT;
```

Then `newuser` will inherit the privileges from `rolw_write`, and there is no need to run `SET ROLE`.